# dig domain replay SOA

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute, nslookup, dig

I have a domain and when I use

```
dig jeeja.biz
```

it just gives me my server ip address.

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
jeeja.biz.      13914   IN  A   209.15.212.171
```

But when I use the same command on another site:

```
dig ilportaledellautomobilista.it
```

the replay is:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ilportaledellautomobilista.it. 3600 IN  SOA dns.it.net. root.dns.it.net. 2012071209 86400 7200 604800 86400
```

What is that and why there is no IP address? 
Why ping, nslookup and traceroute are not working on that specific address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that ilportaledellautomobilista.it does not have an A record, however the domain does exist and does have a nameserver (SOA shows that). Since that host only has a SOA record, thats what dig is returning.

www.ilportaledellautomobilista.it does have an A record though. So give that a try instead, and you will see that A records have been configured for it. Also ilportaledellautomobilista.it is being redirected to www.ilportaledellautomobilista.it (try and type ilportaledellautomobilista.it on its own in a web browser and you will see what I mean)

The A record indicates the host's (domain name) IP. The SOA record indicates what the name server is for that domain. (basically which DNS server its managed from). Since the domain name itself does not have an A record specified, you will not get an IP address returned (thats what the A record is for, to specify an IP).